# This function is not showing the name of files ................... how to resolve this?

Tags: python, image, numpy, directory, information-retrieval

The  name is not showing from test_images In this path there are four images?? How to resolve this
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWvpn.png)

```
paths = "C:/Users/Saad/new Conuting obj/test_images/"

import os
import glob

imagesList = listdir(path)
loaenter image description herededImages = []

for images in imagesList:
    display(os.path.basename(path))
```

Comment: Your provided code is not coherent.

Comment: @BjörnB Sorry, but you edit should absolutely be rejected. It doesn't make the question any better (the rules of SO explicitely ask for the code to be included as text, not images), and the question can't be answered as it is. Furthermore, you left some unrelated text in the very middle of the code. Please be more careful when suggesting edits, and only do them on good, answerable questions.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille ok you are right. Just tried to help here. Saad please refer to the rules of [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You're welcome, keep helping ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This could help

```
import os

paths = "C:/Users/Saad/new Conuting obj/test_images/"
imagesList = os.listdir(paths)

for images in imagesList:
    print(os.path.basename(images))  # instead of basename(path)
```

Comment: Not Working shows only dots

Comment: I get 000-623_1000.jpg
001-976_1000.jpg
002-761_1000.jpg
003-753_1000.jpg
004-745_1000.jpg. Exact same code. Copied from above. Different directory. Maybe your directory path isn't right.

Comment: Your own code is full of errors and unused variables. Before posting run it to get the errors out. For now copy my example and try it. It runs so it should run with you also.